# PNG image file not showing up in html

Tags: html

I am new at programming and my friend gave me a challenge he wanted me to make him a website but this image wont show up here is my code the website is bentrump.cf.

```
 <h1 class="color">  BEN<img id="heath" src="pics/HEATH.PNG" alt="A Heath bar">
    </h1>
```

Comment: You're most likely not targetting the picture correctly. Are you sure it's called "heath" and not "health"

Comment: yes its a picture of a heath bar

Comment: Looking at your website, your `pics` folder doesn't have the `heath.png` file in it

Comment: Perhaps you just got lucky that you didn't engage in Trademark Infringement. True, yes, but it's your file extension. It should be the same as it is on your Server.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many causes for this error.

However, while inspecting the files in your server `pics` directory, we can see the file that you have there:

http://bentrump.cf/pics/

[image]

So you do have the correct file name, but the wrong extension. The extension should be in small letters. So the file name should be HEATH.png

Your code should look like this:

```
<h1 class="color">  BEN<img id="heath" src="pics/HEATH.png" alt="A Heath bar">
    </h1>
```